# to call Jsp from Servlet

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, scriptlet

I want to call the same Jsp from a Servlet

My situation:
Servlet(A) -->Jsp(A) -->Servlet(B)--->Jsp(A)

This code in Servlet(B) doesn't work...why?

```
    ServletContext sc=request.getServletContext();
    RequestDispatcher rd=sc.getRequestDispatcher("/JSP(A)");
    rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: I assume that really isn't the JSP name being passed to requestDispatcher?  What happens when this code executes.

Comment: I have a java.lang.NullPointerException in rd.forward...why?

Comment: Maybe it cannot find the JSP?

Comment: `getRequestDispatcher()` returns `null` if no resource maps to that path in the Servlet container configuration.

Comment: The error is: I call servlet(B) in JSP(A) from <a href="Servlet(B)"?param1&param2> and in servlet(B) I use get method get instead post..How can I solve it?

Comment: It should be `RequestDispatcher rd=sc.getRequestDispatcher("/JSP(A).jsp");` you have to specify the `.jsp` extension. If resource is other than the servlet you must specify the extension also (e.g index.html, index.jsp)